# Какое число употребить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как верно: "Нужно смотреть именно на то, сколько человек поделилось (поделились) ссылкой"?

Comment: А "пожалуйста" Вас не учили говорить?

Comment: "Что ж ты смотришь на сучок в глазу ближнего твоего, а в своем глазу бревна не замечаешь?" (см. свои вопросы).

Comment: Где именно Вы видите мои вопросы? Это раз. Лучше делайте выводы и обратите внимание, сколько за Вами пришлось править, это два. И не спорьте с админами — это три. Да, и учитесь вежливости.

Comment: Ваших вопросов достаточно - 91 (и не все они связаны с модерацией). Нигде "пожалуйста" не замечено что-то. Это раз. Модератор - не монарх-деспот, чтобы сочинять правила на ходу. Нигде в правилах говорить "пожалуста" не прописано. Это два. И три - я сама буду решать, как и что мне говорить. В случае дальнейших терок я знаю, как связаться с реальными админами ресурса, поэтому не утруждайтесь.

Comment: >В случае дальнейших терок я знаю, как связаться с реальными админами ресурса, 

Тоже мне, секрет Полишинеля.
Во многия знания - многия печали (С). Особенно когда знания - тайные.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, тут без разницы. У Розенталя есть, кажется, некое правило, которое очень приблизительно советует писать в единственном числе, если действие производилось группой, и во множественном, если по отдельности. Но это совсем не императив, а некая тенденция, не носящая какой-либо обязательности.

Answer (score 0):

"Нужно смотреть именно на то, сколько человек поделились ссылкой?" Когда речь идет об одушевленных существительных, предпочтительнее форма множественного числа глагола, хотя нередки случаи употребения единственного числа: Сколько людей пришло на митинг! Здесь в содержании предложения есть отттенок собирательности, поэтому возможна форма ед.ч.